# Box shadow circle

Tags: html, css

I want to make shadow in circle like this
[image]

I have tried this:

```
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: #e65525;
border-radius:50%;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #e78267;
```

but it's doing not that what i need. how can I improve that?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zu9rd1jq/)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #e65525;
    border-radius:50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #e78267;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zu9rd1jq/1/).

The problem you had was in your `box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #e78267;` line, in turn:

- `3px` (the first) is the horizontal offset,
- `3px` (the second) is the vertical offset,
- `3px` (the third) is the 'blur' distance.

I've changed that to `box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #e78267;`, because:

- a zero offset (for both horizontal and vertical) means the shadow is centred around the shape itself,
- the third zero provides a blur distance of 0, annd
- the `3px` gives a 'spread' (so you that a solid 'shadow' is given, rather than a blurred shadow).

References:

- [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) ([MDN: CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/)).
- [`box-shadow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-css3-background-20080910/#box-shadow) ([W3.org](http://www.w3.org/).

Answer (score 3):

You were almost there. This is the right code:

```
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 6px #e78267;
```

For your information inset is for shadows inside the shape, first and second parameters are for positioning of shadow(horizontal/vertical), third for blur and fourth for spread. You can play with the spread a little bit if you want less or more shadow inside the circle.

Answer (score 2):

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #e78267
```